# How do insert more than one row into a table using Entity Framework when one column is a foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Please help me.  I can't find this anywhere.  I want to do this with Entity framework when inserting:

- Add *1 row* to table **tParent**
- Add *4 rows* to table **tChildren**.

**tChildren** has a column that is a FK of **tParent** called *ParentID.*

I'm on 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you have *navigational properties* setup on the entities.

`tParent` should have a navigational property called `tChildrens`, and (optionally), `tChildren` should have a navigational property called `tParent`.

The multiplicity should be `tParent` 1..* `tChildren`.

With that in mind, this should do the trick:

```
var parent = new tParent();
var child1 = new tChild();
var child2 = new tChild();
// set properties you need, etc etc
parent.tChildrens.Add(child1);
parent.tChildrens.Add(child2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

EF is smart enough to add the parent, grab the identity, then insert the children with the FK set to the identity just created.

Comment: can I do this in a Loop?  For each ChildItem in Parent.ChildList parent.tChildrens.add(ChildItem)?

Comment: @Sarah - is this a new "Parent", or are you trying to add "Children" to an existing "Parent"?

Comment: The question has to do with new Parent with new Children. Figured I would takle that first before adding new children (or updating children)

Comment: @Sarah - if it's a brand new parent and new children, how can you loop through `parent.tChildrens`? that would imply there are *existing children* to loop through. know what i mean?

Comment: I'm using a DTO objects. My object for Parent includes a property of a list of children (ChildList) in it. So when it gets passed in my service it comes as a Parent (parent name, parent age, ChildList). there is no telling how many children each parent has so writting it as child1 = , child2 = ....doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense

Comment: @Sarah - ok, got ya - you didnt mention your service layer/DTO architecture. Okay, so a object comes in pre-populated. In this case, yes - just loop through the childlist and add each children to the EF parent entity.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add the children to the parent using a loop but need to call save changes once, something like as follows, say the parent is Order and child is called OrderItem

```
    public void AddOrder(OrderDto orderToAdd)
    {
        var newOrder = Order.CreateOrder(orderToAdd.OrderID, .....);  //set all other non nullable attributes
        neworder.OrderDate = orderToAdd.OrderDate;
        //set other properties
        '
        '  
        //then add the order items to the newOrder 
        //note orderToAdd.OrderItemsDto is the ChildList
        foreach (OrderItemDto o in orderToAdd.OrderItemsDto)
        {  
            var orderItem = OrderItem.CreateOrderItem(orderToAdd.OrderID, o.OrderItemID); //set all other non nullable attributes
            orderItem.OrderQuantity = o.OrderQuantity;
            //set other properties
            '  
            '    
            newOrder.OrderItems.Add(orderItem); 
        }
        context.AddToOrders(newOrder);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```